# Managing interface builder's window layout

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I have my macbook pro hooked up to an apple cinema display. I want to work on my code on the laptop but have interface builder on the cinema display. It needs to be this way because my laptop screen doesn't have the resolution to show a full iPad interface layout in IB so I would need to scroll up and down. 
The thing I am fighting with is that whenever I open a XIB, or when IB starts, it places any new app windows back on my laptop screen. Is there any way to define a window layout for IB to use, and tell it to start all windows on my second screen by default? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Interface Builder does not currently save window positions (which include what screen they're on).

You might have limited success using Spaces, which assigns specific applications to specific spaces, but I'm not sure how it would work with multiple screens.